# One-to-one relation on sequelize not working

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize with express.js and MySQL, but i cant get a one-to-one relation to work.

The API always responses the *address_id* with the integer informed in the field, but not with the infos in the *customers_addresses* table. I try to force the eager loading by using *{ include: { all: true }}*, but with no success.

Below is the files involved.

Can someone help ? :)

**How the two tables are created:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers_addresses` 
(`address_id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `numero_casa` VARCHAR(255), 
`complemento` VARCHAR(255), `rua` VARCHAR(255), `bairro` VARCHAR(255), `cidade` 
VARCHAR(255), `estado` VARCHAR(2), `cep` VARCHAR(9), PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`))


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (`customer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment ,
 `first_name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, `cpf` CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
`rg` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `expedidor_rg` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `inss_number` INTEGER,
 `inss_situation` INTEGER, `email` VARCHAR(30), `phone` VARCHAR(20), `gender` VARCHAR(1),
 `civil_state` VARCHAR(255), `address_id` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`), 
FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `customers_addresses` (`address_id`))
```

**The init-models.js file:**

```
function initModels(sequelize) {
  var customers = _customers(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var customers_addresses = _customers_addresses(sequelize, DataTypes);

  customers.hasOne(customers_addresses, { foreignKey: "address_id"});
  customers_addresses.belongsTo(customers, { foreignKey: "address_id"});


  return {
    customers,
    customers_addresses,
  };
}
```

**The customers.js model:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('customers', {
    customer_id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
      allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    cpf: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(11),
      allowNull: false
    },
    rg: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: false
    },
    expedidor_rg: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: false
    },
    inss_number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    inss_situation: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: true
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    gender: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(1),
      allowNull: true
    },
    civil_state: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    address_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      notNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'customers_addresses',
        key: 'address_id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'customers',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

**How the API controller calls it:**

```
customers.findAll({ include: { all: true }})
```

**The query that is finally executed:**

```
Executing (default): SELECT `customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `cpf`, `rg`, `expedidor_rg`, `inss_number`, `inss_situation`, `email`, `phone`, `gender`, `civil_state`, `address_id` FROM `customers` AS `customers`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your API Controller. I think we should call the model name that have associations with the customer table

```
customers.findAll({include: [{model:customer_addresses}]})
```

Comment: with customers.findAll({include: [{model:customer_addresses}]}) i get this:
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Error message: customer_addresses is not defined

Comment: With customers_addresses as model (you missed an 's') is the same thing.

Comment: don't forget to import your customer_adresses model in your API Controller

Comment: Thats a step forward! Now with customers_addresses beeing imported, i get this:
Status: 500
Error message: customers_addresses is not associated to customers!"

Comment: I think there is a problem with your init-models.js. have you execute that function initModels(sequelize) somewhere? i can't explain more since i have limited information

Comment: The function is called everytime the API goes UP (tested with a console.log). But i cant find who is really calling it. This file was created automatically by Sequelize. 

tahanks for your help